# calling a javascript method from within a dropdown list asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a drop down list that when the selected value is of a certin value I need to do some stuff and then redirect to a new page in a new tab

now I figured the best way to do this would be to use either response.wirte() like so

```
Response.Write(<script>);
Response.Write(window.open('url'));
Response.Write(</script>);
```

or Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript() methode to call a javascript methode that would open a new page in a diffrent tab like so

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"GoToURL", "<script language=JavaScript>GoToURL(" + url + ")</script>");
```

and the javascript looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function GoToURL(url)
                {
                    window.open(url);
                }
            </script>
```

I have tried both of these and the response.write methode just coming up with unable to parse the resposnse request and nothing at all happens when I use the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

can anyone see where I have gone wrong with this or of any other possible way to do this

Note that both of these peaces of code were exicuted inside the SelectedIndexChanged method of my drop downlist

Thanks in advance

**Update**
in the end I just caved in and filnally used a button to do the code behind and java script (got to love those onclientclick events :p) as nothing seems to be working to get java script to run from a drop down menu's onselected changed event

Thanks for all your suggestion though :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Based on your comment, I think this is the solution your looking for. you can create a case for each dropdown list value and according those cases, redirect users to different url in a new tab.

```
    protected void ddlAuthoritytype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var port = Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port.ToString();

    string ddl = ddlAuthoritytype.SelectedValue;
    switch (ddl)
    {
        case "AL":
            var script = string.Format("window.open('{0}://{1}{2}{3}')", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, port, ResolveUrl("~/alabama-state-tax-calculator.aspx"));
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow",script, true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this would work but I need to do a lot of code behind as well as the redirect so this means that I can not place the java call in the html (unless there is a onclientchange that i have missed)

Comment: This would not open the page in a new tab which is what I am looking to do

Comment: This was actually the first thing I tried if you look in my question :), this just did nothing and i am unsuer why (was one of the reasons I opened the question), thanks for your help but I have given up on the idea of doing this without some kind of button as it was becoming to time consuming and I have many other projects i need to work on

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hidden Field instead, in the Code behind, set the Hidden Field Value with the URL.

in `pageLoad()` javascript function check the value of the hidden field, if it is not empty, use the `window.open(hiddenFieldValue)` something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad()
    {
        // Use $('#' + '<%= hfURL.ClientID %>') if hidden field has runtat="server"
        if($('#' + '<%= hfURL.ClientID %>').val()) 
            window.open($('#' + '<%= hfURL.ClientID %>').val()); 
            // OR window.open($("hfURL").val(), '_blank');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this look like it will work, just going to go try this now

Comment: for some reason this just keeps saying can not find the control, even when I am taking the client name of the control from the clientID property, could the java script page load method fire before the controls (in the case a masterpage, the content tag and then the hidden field) are loaded?

Comment: mybad :) so sorry i forgot to add '#' before the control Name.
do you use asp.net HiddenField ? if so please let me know to update the code.

Comment: yes i am using an asp.net hidden field, does this make a diffrence to the code?

Comment: I updated the code to access server side hidden field control

Comment: the difference is when you use HTML hidden input, it is client-side control that you can access directly using its ID. Server-Side controls however should be accessed in the way edited in my code above using <%= ctrlID.ClientID %>

Comment: comes up with the correct id but still just say object expected? anyway i got to go for now but i will try agian tomorrow thanks for your help, i will mark your awnser if sucessful :)

Comment: please feel free to post your comments again when you get back to it.

appreciate your help.

Comment: Just figured out why this wasn't working for me, is this by any chance using jquerry and not plain javascript as i do not have jquerry installed on my machine

Comment: Yes, the '$' is the shortcut to JQuery.
Plain JS would be something like: document.getElementById('#' + '<%= hfURL.ClientID %>').value;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in both conditions when page is post back and return to html they have not found your JavaScript function ie: GoToUrl() because it is not initially loaded.
You can call `window.open(url);` method in your C# button click event. like this:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"GoToURL", "<script language=JavaScript>window.open(" + url + ");</script>");
```

I have not tried this but I think this should worked.

Hope this will help